# Manifest.json not found codeigniter pwa application

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

Hi i'm trying to setup pwa support for my website and getting a 404 manifest.json not found error , i'm using codeigniter 3.0 and added the manifest.json at the root folder.

and added the path at header like ,

```
<link rel='manifest' href='/manifest.json'>
```

Please help , Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a mistake with the file name , i named mainfest.json instead of manifest.json . No problem with codeigniter or other things .

:)